# Function SUMIF doesn't work in the entire range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an issue with `SUMIF` function that drives me crazy. The thing is that looks like the Excel calculate the `SUMIF` till a point and not in the entire cells range (even with same length in `range` and `sum_range`).

---

Here's the example:

```
     A        B         C
-------------------------------
1|   5   |  Type1   |   50
2|  10   |  Type2   |    
3|   5   |  Type2   |   35
4|  10   |  Type1   |
5|   5   |  Type2   |
```

---

`C3` is the cell that contains the `SUMIF` function like this: `=C1-SUMIF(B1:B5;"Type2";A1:A5)` (`C1` has a simple `SUM` function from other data) but as you can see the function doesn't work propertry. `C3` shuld have the value `30` instead of `35`. The value of `A5` ins't sume in the `SUMIF`, and so on if you continue to adds rows to the table (even updating the ranges).

That's my problem here. The `SUMIF` function is right: `range;criteria;sum_range` so why isn't analyzing data in the entire `A1:A5 B1:B5` range? What i'm doing wrong?

*- I'm using Excel 2016*

Comment: Are you sure the value in all the cells is "Type2"? i.e. an extra space at the end may throw off the `SUMIF`

Comment: More pointedly, you're right that "`C3` should have the value `30` instead of `35`", but whatever's going on here, "the function doesn't work properly" is not it. When I set up the scenario as described here, the values are correct. If it's not @cybernetic.nomad 's suggestion that you have trailing spaces, there's something else you haven't told us (or noticed) that's throwing you off.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I'm 99% sure because since the first time `Type2` where typed, I used Excel's autocomplete for write the others

Comment: @AlexM of course the real case is a lot more complex economic data table. But, the example is almost like the real one: in the function is only involved _Currency_ (`A` column) and _General_ (`B` column)data types for all the cases. The other think is that `C1` are involved in the operation, but `C1` is just a simple `SUM(D1:D5)` if `D` column exists. This operation `=C1-SUMIF(*;*;*)` can be a problem?

Comment: What happens if you try: `=C1-SUMIF(B:B;"Type2";A:A)`?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I think I can't try that, threw me an error because in the real case `A1` and `B1` are in fact `A9` and `B9`, above of them are other cells with other information and data type

Comment: Sounds like there is more to this spreadsheet than we can know with the info we have. Try checking the ranges formulas refer to.

Comment: @AlexM following your observation that " there's something else you haven't told us (or noticed) that's throwing you off" I'm reviewing all the `SUMIF` purpose for the kind of information I want to obtaing, and I'm thinking isn't a problem with the result itself, but with the algorythm for get that information I want... I'll try the worksheet a little more with real data to see if i'm wrong with the method or there are a real problem with the use of the function

Comment: There you go. Constructing a trivial example - which worked as expected - led you to discover an assumption you hadn't realized you had made in production. Another win for the rubber duck.

Comment: I didn't find any problem with the formula. 0.0?

Comment: @FiroKun,, nothing wrong with the formula since I've successfully produced the desire result `30`!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was isn't in the function itself, but in my interpretation of the information the formula output. Since `C1` depends on the same data `SUMIF` use in `sum_range`, when I introduce new `Type2` data, not only `C3` was update, also `C1`, and since `C3` output depends of `C1` like `=C1-SUMIF(B1:B5;"Type2";A1:A5)` so `C3` where updated by two ways: `C1` data and `SUMIF` output, making I not interpretated correctly the result. I need to put more caution in this things.

Comment: Better upload illustration to justify how you have solved the issue !